# Documentation about filters in general

Tags: language-agnostic, filter, theory

Lately I am involved in processing data from sensors from different devices. These sensors consist of accelerometers, gyroscopes, magnetometers etc. It all started when I wanted to isolate the gravitational force and stumbled upon this link (code from android  android_frameworks_base / services / sensorservice / SecondOrderLowPassFilter.cpp ):

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cutils/log.h>

#include "SecondOrderLowPassFilter.h"

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace android {
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

SecondOrderLowPassFilter::SecondOrderLowPassFilter(float Q, float fc)
    : iQ(1.0f / Q), fc(fc)
{
}

void SecondOrderLowPassFilter::setSamplingPeriod(float dT)
{
    K = tanf(float(M_PI) * fc * dT);
    iD = 1.0f / (K*K + K*iQ + 1);
    a0 = K*K*iD;
    a1 = 2.0f * a0;
    b1 = 2.0f*(K*K - 1)*iD;
    b2 = (K*K - K*iQ + 1)*iD;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

BiquadFilter::BiquadFilter(const SecondOrderLowPassFilter& s)
    : s(s)
{
}

float BiquadFilter::init(float x)
{
    x1 = x2 = x;
    y1 = y2 = x;
    return x;
}

float BiquadFilter::operator()(float x)
{
    float y = (x + x2)*s.a0 + x1*s.a1 - y1*s.b1 - y2*s.b2;
    x2 = x1;
    y2 = y1;
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
    return y;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

CascadedBiquadFilter::CascadedBiquadFilter(const SecondOrderLowPassFilter& s)
    : mA(s), mB(s)
{
}

float CascadedBiquadFilter::init(float x)
{
    mA.init(x);
    mB.init(x);
    return x;
}

float CascadedBiquadFilter::operator()(float x)
{
    return mB(mA(x));
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}; // namespace android
```

While that code does work quite well I feel like I need to understand some basics about the filter philosophy in general. For example maybe I need to change something in that filter.

I started reading on Wikipedia (Kalman, Low-Pass, ...) but I still feel like I need to feel/touch this theory better before starting to modify someone else's code.

So I'm asking you, SO users, what can I read in order to have a more than general idea about filters? Any link, resource, documentation will be good.

Also: I have an engineer degree but didn't quite study filters except for some Fourier transformations (DFT) when studying signal processing. Math should not be a big issue.

I'm asking this question because I saw there are **MANY** questions related to filters.

Thanks a lot,

Iulian

Comment: You may get good answers here, but also in http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @INS : Google codesearch has been shutdown. Can you please give another link?

Comment: @Ashwin done. I've put the source code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a less complicated introduction at [dspguide](http://www.dspguide.com) in the following chapters:

- [Chapter 14: Introduction to Digital Filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch14.htm)
- [Chapter 15: Moving Average Filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch15.htm)
- [Chapter 16: Windowed-Sinc Filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch16.htm)
- [Chapter 17: Custom Filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch17.htm)
- [Chapter 19: Recursive Filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch19.htm)
- [Chapter 20: Chebyshev Filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch20.htm)
- [Chapter 21: Filter Comparison](http://www.dspguide.com/ch21.htm)

---

More interesting answers [here on dsp stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/231/documentation-about-filters-in-general).

---

PS: I made this a wiki so people can add their resources (contributions are welcome).

---